# Change bitmap format using glide and BitmapTypeRequest

Tags: java, android, bitmap, android-glide

Don't know how to do this :

How to change the DecodeFormat on a bitmap that I want to use as a Request :

```
final BitmapTypeRequest<?> request = Glide.with(context)
            .load(uri)
            .asBitmap(); // here should be .format(DecodeFormat.PREFER_ARGB_8888)

    final SimpleTarget target = new SimpleTarget() {

        @Override
        public void onResourceReady(Object resource, GlideAnimation glideAnimation) {
            memCache.put(nameString, resource);
        }
    };

    // Must be executed on main thread
    context.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            request.into(target);
        }
    });
```

**Problem is :** `.format(DecodeFormat.PREFER_ARGB_8888)` return a `BitmapRequestBuilder` and I need a `BitmapTypeRequest`

EDIT :

This operation works perfectly :

```
 Glide.with(context)
                .load(uri)
                .asBitmap()
                .format(DecodeFormat.PREFER_ARGB_8888)
                .into(imageView);
```

But as you can see I cache the bitmaps so this method is not good for my use case.

Comment: Glide includes a memory cache. Not only do you not need to cache resources yourself, it's unsafe to do so because Glide pools and re-uses them (Bitmaps in particular). What option are you trying to use that requires BitmapTypeRequest and not BitmapRequestBuilder?

Comment: I configure a custom GlideLruCache, and set it's size in a GlideModule. Normally I would use the default cache method used by Glide, but in this particular case I need the image to be loaded into memory before being displayed so that it'll apear immediatly (no loading, no white screen). The images can be really big so this is the only method i've found. With the default DecodeFormat it works without any issue. But on some devices I see artefacts in the images. ARGB_8888 solve that issue. As you can see with normal use it's easy, but in my case i'm stuck

Answer (score 0):

Check [this](https://inthecheesefactory.com/blog/get-to-know-glide-recommended-by-google/en) guide. You need to add GlideModule which customize the builder, and then apply it trough the manifest.

Comment: But I want only this BitmapFormat for some images not for all of them (please try to add more detail than an external link)

Comment: Sorry, havent used Glide- but as far as i can see you cant change this settings per request- only globally.